# Facing difficulty in Implementing Carousel when iterating through an array

Tags: html, css, reactjs, carousel, bootstrap-5

I want to implement carousel using data from my Vidoes Array, i am unable to obtain desired output instead all the videos in the Array are rendered at the same time

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            {Videos}
        </div>
      </div>




This is my Videos array

const Videos = VIDEOS.map((vid) => {
      if(vid.name=="Video1"){
        vari=true;
        }
      return (
        <div
         className={vari?"carousel-item active":"carousel-item"}
          style={{ width: "25vw", height: "5vh", background: "#F1F1F1",margin:"auto" }}
        >
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt={vid.name}></img>
        </div>
      );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done just this a couple of days ago.. Have yet to shorten, optimize and add video support though

here's my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import "./MediaViewer.css";
import { useGlobalObj, globalObj } from 'logic/zergski-global-object';

// content JSON
import { mediaJSON } from 'logic/content-collections';

// components
import Anchor from 'shared/Anchor';

let current = 'can1';
let canvas = {
    can1: {
        pos: 'center',
        trans: true,
        source: mediaJSON[0].src,
    },
    can2: {
        pos: 'right',
        trans: true,
        source: mediaJSON[1].src,
    },
    can3: {
        pos: 'left',
        trans: false,
        source: mediaJSON[mediaJSON.length-1].src,
    }
}

// iterator
// TODO! add settings
const iterator = ( array, setState, initIndex ) => {
    let index = initIndex;
    let count = array.length - 1;   // content count
    let nextSource = index+2;       // next imagesource to load
    let nextCanvas = 0; //  canvas position
    let nextImageSource = nextCanvas - 1;

    return {
        next() {
            index = index === count ? 0 : ++index;
            nextSource = index+1 > count ? 0 : index+1;

            Object.entries(canvas).forEach( c => {
                canvas[c[0]].pos = c[1].pos === 'center' ? 'left' : c[1].pos === 'right' ? 'center' : 'right';
                c[1].pos === 'center' && (current = c[0]);
                if ( c[1].pos === 'right' ) {
                    canvas[c[0]].trans = false;
                    canvas[c[0]].source = mediaJSON[nextSource].src;
                } else {
                    canvas[c[0]].trans = true;
                }
            });

            setState({
                ...canvas,
                counter: index+1,
            });
        },
        prev() {
            index = index === 0 ? count : --index;
            nextSource = index-1 < 0 ? count : index-1;

            Object.entries(canvas).forEach( c => {
                canvas[c[0]].pos = c[1].pos === 'center' ? 'right' : c[1].pos === 'left' ? 'center' : 'left';
                c[1].pos === 'center' && (current = c[0]);
                if ( c[1].pos === 'left' ) {
                    canvas[c[0]].trans = false;
                    canvas[c[0]].source = mediaJSON[nextSource].src;
                } else {
                    canvas[c[0]].trans = true;
                }
            });

            setState({
                ...canvas,
                counter: index+1,
            });
        }
    }
}



var lastTouch = 0;
var content = Object.create(null);

// component for viewing images, videos and documents
const MediaViewer = props => {
    const mediaViewer = {
        display: 'hidden',
        contentIndex: 0,
        initialState: { display: 'hidden' },
    }
    const [ viewerState, setViewerState ] = useGlobalObj({ mediaViewer });
    const [ state, setState ] = useState({
        ...canvas,
        counter: 1,
    });
    const [ touchState, setTouchState ] = useState({
        touch: false,
        movement: 0,
    });




    if ( viewerState.display === 'show' ) {
        document.body.classList.add('scroll-lock');
        setTimeout(()=>{
            globalObj.mediaViewer.setState({ display: 'visible' });
        }, 50)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const { display, index } = viewerState;
        if ( display === 'show' ) {
            content = iterator( mediaJSON, setState, index );

            current = 'can1';
            canvas = {
                can1: {
                    pos: 'center',
                    trans: false,
                    source: mediaJSON[index].src,
                },
                can2: {
                    pos: 'right',
                    trans: false,
                    source: mediaJSON[index === mediaJSON.length-1 ? 0 : index+1].src,
                },
                can3: {
                    pos: 'left',
                    trans: false,
                    source: mediaJSON[index === 0 ? mediaJSON.length-1 : index-1].src,
                }
            }

            setState({
                ...canvas,
                counter: index+1,
            })
        }

    }, [viewerState]);

    const handleClose = () => {
        globalObj.mediaViewer.setState({ display: 'hide' });
        setTimeout(()=>{
            globalObj.mediaViewer.setState({ display: 'hidden' });
        }, 400)

        document.body.classList.remove('scroll-lock');
    }



    // input handlers
    const handleMovement = ( delta, touch=false ) => {
        let nextMovement = touchState.movement - delta;


        canvas[current].trans = false;
        canvas[current].movement = nextMovement;
        setTouchState({ movement: nextMovement });
    }
    // touch
    const handleTouchStart = (e) => {
        lastTouch = e.nativeEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    }
    const handleTouchMove = (e) => {
        const delta = lastTouch - e.nativeEvent.touches[0].clientX;
        lastTouch = e.nativeEvent.touches[0].clientX;

        handleMovement(Math.floor(delta), true);
    }
    const handleTouchEnd = (e) => {
        touchState.movement < -50 ? content.next() : touchState.movement > 50 && content.prev();
        lastTouch = 0;

        canvas[current].trans = true;
        setTouchState({ movement: 0 });
    }

    return (

        <div className={ `Media-Viewer ${ viewerState.display }` }
            onTouchStart={ handleTouchStart }
            onTouchMove={ handleTouchMove }
            onTouchEnd={ handleTouchEnd }
        >

            <img className={ `Media-Viewer-Content ${ state.can1.pos }` } alt={ '' }
                src={ state.can1.source }

                style={{
                    transform: current === 'can1' ? `translateX(${ touchState.movement }px)` : '',
                    transitionDuration: `${ canvas.can1.trans ? '' : '0s' }`,
                }}
            />
            <img className={ `Media-Viewer-Content ${ state.can2.pos }` } alt={ '' }

                src={ state.can2.source }

                style={{
                    transform: current === 'can2' ? `translateX(${ touchState.movement }px)` : '',
                    transitionDuration: `${ canvas.can2.trans ? '' : '0s' }`,
                }}
            />
            <img className={ `Media-Viewer-Content ${ state.can3.pos }` } alt={ '' }
                src={ state.can3.source }

                style={{
                    transform: current === 'can3' ? `translateX(${ touchState.movement }px)` : '',
                    transitionDuration: `${ canvas.can3.trans ? '' : '0s' }`,
                }}
            />

            <div className="Modal-User-Interface-Wrapper">
                <div className="Information-Box">
                    <h4>{ `${ state.counter }/${ mediaJSON.length }` }</h4>
                </div>
                <Anchor
                    altClass="icon"
                    fileName="cross.svg"
                    style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '0', right: '0', opacity: '.5' }}
                    clicked={ handleClose }
                />
                <Anchor
                    altClass="icon"
                    fileName="arrow.svg"
                    style={{ transform: 'rotate(180deg)' }}
                    clicked={ ()=>content.prev() }
                />
                <Anchor
                    altClass="icon"
                    fileName="arrow.svg"
                    clicked={ ()=>content.next() }
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default MediaViewer;
```

And CSS

```
.Media-Viewer {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: calc(100*var(--vh));
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;

    transition: opacity .4s ease;
}
.Media-Viewer.hide,
.Media-Viewer.show {
    opacity: 0;
}
.Media-Viewer.hidden {
    display: none;
}


.Media-Viewer-Content {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    transition: transform .4s ease;

    will-change: transform;
}
.Media-Viewer-Content.center {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
.Media-Viewer-Content.right {
    transform: translate3d(100vw,0,0);
}
.Media-Viewer-Content.left {
    transform: translate3d(-100vw,0,0);
}


.Modal-User-Interface-Wrapper {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: calc( 100vw - (100vw - 300px) / 10 );
    opacity: .6;
    height: calc(100*var(--vh));
    z-index: 10;
    transition: opacity 1.2s ease;
    transition-delay: 4s;
}


.Media-Viewer .Anchor {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    height: 3.5rem;
    width: 3.5rem;
    padding: 1rem .7rem 1rem 1rem;
    opacity: .1;
    margin-bottom: 1.7rem;
    border-radius: 4rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity, background-color .7s ease;
    z-index: 10;
    transition-duration: .44s;
}

.Media-Viewer .Anchor:hover,
.Media-Viewer:active .Modal-User-Interface-Wrapper,
.Media-Viewer-Content:active .Modal-User-Interface-Wrapper {
    opacity: .9;
    transition-duration: .1s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
.Media-Viewer .Anchor:hover {
    opacity: .7;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.089);
}


/* overlay */
.Media-Viewer::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 8;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.932);
    backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    z-index: -1;
}



.Information-Box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: .4rem; right: 0; left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 2.7rem;
    width: calc(3rem + 10vw);
    background: rgb(220,148,87);
    background: linear-gradient(133deg, rgba(32, 28, 24, 0.719) 0%, rgba(43, 32, 26, 0.582) 100%);
    border-radius: .6rem;

    z-index: 10;
}

.Information-Box h4 {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: .85rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgb(1, 4, 5);
}
```

Maybe you'll find something useful here..

Comment: Otherwise if you want the to smoothly scroll to the side.. stack them side to side with `flex-direction: row` animate `transform: translateX` and trigger playback with an 'intersectionObserver'..

Comment: can u give me exact code as iam facing some difficulty is implementing the above code

Comment: for what solution? continuous horizontal scroll or infinite next/prev switch?